# Trying to set an item on a combobox

Tags: java

Trying to set the item on my combobox but it does not do anything and there is no errors. this is how it looks.

```
  if(  fe.getAdmin()==0){
   Admincombo.setSelectedItem(1);
  }
  if(fe.getAdmin()==1){
   Admincombo.setSelectedItem(0);
  }
  }
```

fe.getAdmin (returns a int) either returns a 1 or a 0 I have tested this. The combobox only has 2 items. Programming is netbeans

Comment: Does this code run in EDT? Try using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and see whether it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select an item with the **index** (What I think you're trying to do):

```
Admincombo.setSelectedIndex(anIndex);
```

If you want to select an item-**name**:

```
Admincombo.setSelectedItem(aString);
```

Comment: Thanks! What a stupid mistake I made :P Thanks for taking the time to awnser this for me :P